# redbeanphp ОРМ, проблема при выводе столбца в котором присутствует заглавная буква

Tags: php, sql, база-данных, redbeanphp

Суть: Хочу вывести цену книги с названием `Fredelon`, я могу сделать это так

```
 $book  = R::findOne( 'books', ' bookname = ? ', [ 'Fredelon' ] );
 echo $book->price;
```

И все будет отлично!

Но, в базе данных с которой я сейчас работаю, все столбцы названы `sPrice`, `sMenu`, `sUsers`, которые не хотят выводиться, выводит только если убираю заглавные буквы с названий. При попытке `var_dump($book->sPrice)` выводит `NULL`

Возможно ли решить проблему не прибегая к варианту с переписью всех названий?

Comment: попробуйте ему сделать `print_r(R::inspect('books'))`, как он поле назовет. а вообще имена `sPrice` согласно документации преобразуются в `s_price`

Comment: и что будет, если сделать дамп не поля, а самого объекта, как он там поля зовет?

Comment: print_r(R::inspect('books')) и дамп объекта $book показывает их правильно - sPrice (как и записано в бд) но при попытке вывода - echo $book->sPrice - выводит пустоту(null)... убираю большую букву в бд - сразу все нормально..

Comment: я же вам написал, что `sPrice` транслируется в `s_price` согласно [документации (абзац conventions)](https://redbeanphp.com/index.php?p=/crud)

Comment: при попытке вывода echo $book->s_price также пустота, null

Comment: дак у вас же нет поля `s_price` в БД

Comment: в общем если хотите использовать данный ORM, то используйте его как положено,  не надо ставить его и начинать ломать. переименуйте поля БД чтобы они соответствовали соглашениями об именовании данного ORM. Можете попробовать реализовать отдельный метод для извлечения полей в обход стандартного механизма, но сначала потребуется извлечь, потом записать, и т.д. Либо возьмите другой фреймворк